# Creating a responsive html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking for a good solution for making a responsive html table, I'm currently using bootstrap to do this. When the table is shown a smaller device e.g. iPad the table becomes scrollable. However I want a better solution than this, so it looks neater and more professional on the small devices.

Example of a solution which looks great on a iPad and what i'm trying to achieve:

```js
$('table').DataTable();

// See:
// http://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-data-tables-comprehensive-list-solutions
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 140%;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
table caption {
  padding: .5em 0;
}
table.dataTable th,
table.dataTable td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 140px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.4/css/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.4/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>


<h2>Responsive Table with DataTables</h2>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <table summary="This table shows how to create responsive tables using Datatables' extended functionality" class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
        <caption class="text-center">An example of a responsive table based on <a href="https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/" target="_blank">DataTables</a>:</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Languages</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Median Age</th>
            <th>Area (Km²)</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Argentina</td>
            <td>Spanish (official), English, Italian, German, French</td>
            <td>41,803,125</td>
            <td>31.3</td>
            <td>2,780,387</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Australia</td>
            <td>English 79%, native and other languages</td>
            <td>23,630,169</td>
            <td>37.3</td>
            <td>7,739,983</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Greece</td>
            <td>Greek 99% (official), English, French</td>
            <td>11,128,404</td>
            <td>43.2</td>
            <td>131,956</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Luxembourg</td>
            <td>Luxermbourgish (national) French, German (both administrative)</td>
            <td>536,761</td>
            <td>39.1</td>
            <td>2,586</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Russia</td>
            <td>Russian, others</td>
            <td>142,467,651</td>
            <td>38.4</td>
            <td>17,076,310</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>Swedish, small Sami- and Finnish-speaking minorities</td>
            <td>9,631,261</td>
            <td>41.1</td>
            <td>449,954</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="text-center">Data retrieved from <a href="http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0855611.html" target="_blank">infoplease</a> and <a href="http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/" target="_blank">worldometers</a>.</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="p">Demo by George Martsoukos. <a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-data-tables-comprehensive-list-solutions" target="_blank">See article</a>.</p>
```

However I'm looking for a JQuery/JavaScript or CSS solution only.

**I don't want to use any plugins like datatables.**

Does anybody have any idea how this could be done like the example solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few methods.
The one I tend to use is using meida queries applied to is so that when the screen is too narrow, it reformats (via only CSS) to make each row a bit like it's own table.

http://jsfiddle.net/hbkq02kr/

CSS

```
@media
    only screen and (max-width: 760px),
    (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

        /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
        table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
            display: block;
        }

        /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
        thead tr {
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

        td {
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%;
        }

        td:before {
            /* Now like a table header */
            position: absolute;
            /* Top/left values mimic padding */
            top: 6px;
            left: 6px;
            width: 45%;
            padding-right: 10px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        /*
        Label the data
        */
        td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
        td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
        td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
        td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
        td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
        td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 320px)
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 320px; }
        }

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
        body {
            width: 495px;
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<h1>Responsive Table</h1>

<p>This is the exact same table, only has @media queries applied to is so that when the screen is too narrow, it reformats (via only CSS) to make each row a bit like it's own table. This makes for much more repetition and vertical space needed, but it fits within the horizontal space, so only natural vertical scrolling is needed to explore the data.</p>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Job Title</th>
        <th>Favorite Color</th>
        <th>Wars or Trek?</th>
        <th>Porn Name</th>
        <th>Date of Birth</th>
        <th>Dream Vacation City</th>
        <th>GPA</th>
        <th>Arbitrary Data</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Matman</td>
        <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
        <td>Lettuce Green</td>
        <td>Trek</td>
        <td>Digby Green</td>
        <td>January 13, 1979</td>
        <td>Gotham City</td>
        <td>3.1</td>
        <td>RBX-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The</td>
      <td>Tick</td>
      <td>Crimefighter Sorta</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Wars</td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>July 19, 1968</td>
      <td>Athens</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>Edlund, Ben (July 1996).</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jokey</td>
      <td>Smurf</td>
      <td>Giving Exploding Presents</td>
      <td>Smurflow</td>
      <td>Smurf</td>
      <td>Smurflane Smurfmutt</td>
      <td>Smurfuary Smurfteenth, 1945</td>
      <td>New Smurf City</td>
      <td>4.Smurf</td>
      <td>One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cindy</td>
      <td>Beyler</td>
      <td>Sales Representative</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Wars</td>
      <td>Lori Quivey</td>
      <td>July 5, 1956</td>
      <td>Paris</td>
      <td>3.4</td>
      <td>3451</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Captain</td>
      <td>Cool</td>
      <td>Tree Crusher</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Wars</td>
      <td>Steve 42nd</td>
      <td>December 13, 1982</td>
      <td>Las Vegas</td>
      <td>1.9</td>
      <td>Under the couch</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)

Comment: This is something I'd like, however would there be a way of changing the table to show `first column` for each `row` and then have it when the row is clicked show the rest of the columns. So like a collapsed method for the rows?

Comment: Look at http://jsfiddle.net/hbkq02kr/1/ . This is just a quick hack to show you its possible. Click on the persons name when at a lower resolution.

Comment: this exactly what I wanted. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just released a js tool that does just that, it basically use a system like in datatables.net, where a row containing the collapsed content is added below the original row: take a look at my [gif demo](https://lingtalfi.com/img/universe/JResponsiveTableHelper/responsive-table-helper.gif), and the source code is all [here](https://github.com/lingtalfi/JResponsiveTableHelper).

Hope this helps.

Ps: this tool depends on jquery.

Answer (score -1):

since you don't want any plugins, as far as i know the are only three options

1. is a scrollable table like the bootstrap one, you are already using
2. you could hide some colums that are not that important... you can achieve that by using `media queries`
3. you could resize the font size with media queries, but this isn't really an option, i think, because the usability suffers from that